# aggregate data (java.util.Map) format to construct a JSON payloads.

Tags: mule

How would I aggregate data (java.util.Map) format to construct a JSON payloads.
Eg -

```
"listings": [
   {
       "listingId":"7676762734623",
       "section": "section-100",
       "products": 
       [

           {"row":"A4","seat":"11"}
       ]
   },
  ... 100 more such listings arrays
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groovy in scripting:component and the use a json transformer or use a Custom Transformer. See this example:

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
       <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
            Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map1.put("fill","none");
            map1.put("stroke","#fff");  
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("content", map1);
            return map;]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I have {"eventId":"9034782","externalListingId":"12208279","quantity":"2","section":"Upper Box 527","pricePerProduct":"35.785","products":["{row: 1,seat: 1}","{row: 1,seat: 2}"]} . I want to add Listing as head element

Comment: I think that this json is the result from a REST service. So, this json (result) convert to a map using <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/> then add the listing as a head element and use <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/> in order to get the final json.

Comment: I am using JSONSlurper to achieve this. However I cannot pass a variable to it. eg - def s= "new" ; slurper.parseText('s') is giving an error!!

Comment: I think that you can modify your question in order to have all the details. What do you really want to do?

Comment: How would I add variables to sluper object be parsed later -

eg- def s = "new"

def slurper = new JsonSlurper() def result = slurper.parseText('"listings":{"status":s}')

This is giving an error! How can I also append list instead of string

Comment: I realized that you are using groovy component in mule flow. The final result in each step is stored in payload, you should work with this object.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a Java component that aggregates data to a Map and convert that to  a JSON message. Please go through this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819710/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-map-to-a-json-representation-using-jackson-without)