# Convert Map to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, gson

How can I convert a Map to a valid JSON using Jackson?

I am doing it using Google's GSON via a Spring Boot REST Post method...

Here's the RESTful Web Service:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myservice")
public class ValidationService {    

    @RequestMapping(value="/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void validate(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(payload); 
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

So, when I invoke it using this:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST -d '{"name":"value"}' http://localhost:8080/myservice/validate
```

Receive the following to stdout (this is exactly what I want):

```
{"name":"value"}
```

Is there a better way to do this using Jackson instead of Google's Gson and / or am I going about it the wrong way altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson Vs. Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson)

Comment: Neeraj Jain, Thanks for the comment but: Jackson vs. Gson is about the positives and negatives of Jackson vs. Gson. This post is a specific question.

Answer (score 153):

You can convert `Map` to `JSON` using Jackson as follows:

```
Map<String,String> payload = new HashMap<>();
payload.put("key1","value1");
payload.put("key2","value2");

String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload);
System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: This is Map to String, not JSON. There will be another step to convert output string to JSON type.

Comment: @NayanWadekar this actually works, I think you are mistaken or maybe you'd like to provide some insight?

Comment: @BrunoBossola Sorry, I was thinking about actual JSON object, didn't saw the output required, for JSON string representation, this is correct.

Comment: @Mithun Is this efficient in case you want to do this million times? My program goes out of memory, maybe Objectmapper is holding on to a lot of memory while converting these objects?

Comment: it throws erro unreported exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @Mithun, Will it work if my map is like this? Map<String, Object> snsMessage = new HashMap<>();

Answer (score 8):

Using jackson, you can do it as follows:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String clientFilterJson = "";
    try {
        clientFilterJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(filterSaveModel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Will it work if my map is like this?  Map<String, Object> snsMessage = new HashMap<>();

Comment: @Deva ensure that your Objects are not recursive; you made need to mark the reentrant object pointers with Exclude to break the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer Object Mapper instead. Here is the link for the same : [Object Mapper - Spring MVC way of Obect to JSON](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jackson, better to convert directly to ObjectNode.

```
//not including SerializationFeatures for brevity
static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

//pass it your payload
public static ObjectNode convObjToONode(Object o) {
    StringWriter stringify = new StringWriter();
    ObjectNode objToONode = null;

    try {
        mapper.writeValue(stringify, o);
        objToONode = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(stringify.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(objToONode);
    return objToONode;
}
```