# Not able to parse JSON without double quotes in Java using FasterXML Jackson

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

Here is my RAW Json data :
`{ht_missingConditions=null, employeeNumber=UMB1075962, firstName=Pete}`

**Note:** there is no double quotes

My Java Class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MBIdClass {

    private String ht_missingConditions; 
    private String name; 
    private String employeeNumber; 

//All setter getters
}
```

My Utility to convert JSON

```
public static Map<String,String> test(String json) {
        ObjectMapper om=new ObjectMapper();
        om.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
        om.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);
        try {
            return om.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Earlier I tried with passing Generic class but now I am trying at least it parse and convert into `HashMap`.

I am calling using below ways

```
Map<String, String> testObj = test(sanitizedcleanData);
```

I am ending up below error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'UMB1075962': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"{ht_missingConditions:null, employeeNumber:UMB1075962, firstName:Pete  st"[truncated 1569 chars]; line: 1, column: 54]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:703)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2853)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1899)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:968)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:512)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3023)
    at com.devsoftbd.palash.studentsinfo.utils.CommonUtils.test(CommonUtils.java:80)
    at com.devsoftbd.palash.studentsinfo.StudentsInfoApplication.lambda$0(StudentsInfoApplication.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.devsoftbd.palash.studentsinfo.StudentsInfoApplication.main(StudentsInfoApplication.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I have tried to replace `=` with `:` but still no luck
I was referring below article : [StackOverflow-Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387626/unexpected-character-code-61-while-parsing-jsonstring)

Comment: Note it's `ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES`, which handles the _names_ but not the _values_.   Unquoted string values are invalid JSON.  Take a look at this likely dup https://stackoverflow.com/q/15005185/18157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of your JSON string is invalid, it looks more like [Properies class in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-properties-class-java/).

Therefore, you can transform your invalid JSON string by replacing some characters to meet the format of [`.properties`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) file, and then use `Properties` to read it as follows:

```java
String inputStr = "{ht_missingConditions=null, employeeNumber=UMB1075962, firstName=Pete}";

inputStr = inputStr.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace(",", "\r\n");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
System.out.println(properties.toString()); // {ht_missingConditions=null, firstName=Pete, employeeNumber=UMB1075962}
```

Or you can also convert it to a `Map` and get similar result:

```java
Map<String, String> propMap = properties.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> String.valueOf(e.getKey()),
                e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue()),
                (prev, next) -> next, HashMap::new
        ));
System.out.println(propMap.toString()); // {firstName=Pete, ht_missingConditions=null, employeeNumber=UMB1075962}
```