# Java Map to JSON string

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I need to convert a map to JSON string, I am using a third-party library and one of the classes in it has a field of type `Map<String, Object>` I need to convert that map to JSON string and send it to its destination. All works ok until I put a string into that map as a value i.e. if that `Object` in the map is a `String` then I end up having four double quotes (`""value""`) in the final JSON string I get from `jackson`'s `OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(str)` method.

e.g. the following this map:

`map.put("key", "value")` of type `Map<String, Object>` will result in `{"key" : ""value""}` which obviously is not a JSON string, any idea how to resolve this without writing a custom method to check types and solve the issue?

Comment: Have you  considered using GSON? https://github.com/google/gson
This should be very trival

Comment: I need to use jackson

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340383/convert-map-to-json-using-jackson

Comment: Can you share your code? Jackson's Object Mapper should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use com.google.gson.Gson

```
   public void convertMapToJson() {
        SortedMap<String, String> elements = new TreeMap();
        elements.put("Key1", "Value1");
        elements.put("Key2", "Value2");
        elements.put("Key3", "Value3");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type gsonType = new TypeToken<HashMap>(){}.getType();
        String gsonString = gson.toJson(elements,gsonType);
        System.out.println(gsonString);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to use jackson only