# How to change dataType from Map to Json in Java

Tags: java, json

Now my Ajax returns the data structure is:

```
{
list=[
     {id=1, name=null, pwd=qqqqqq, username=chenming, tel=18686868686, age=null, state=1, place=null, entertime=null, dept=null, idcard=null},
     {id=7, name=null, pwd=111111, username=suixin, tel=18686868686, age=null, state=1, place=null, entertime=null, dept=null, idcard=null}
], currentPage=1
}
```

Now return dataType is Map.But i need Json to traversal object ,and use them in JSP. If i need Jackson or other ways?

Comment: May be you are looking for : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819710/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-map-to-a-json-representation-using-jackson-without](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819710/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-map-to-a-json-representation-using-jackson-without)

Comment: Thanks, it is useful for me!